# Verification of solution to differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I need help to verify a solution to a partial differential equation. Here is the solution:

$$f_t(s)=2 \sqrt{\frac{t}{s}}K_1(2\sqrt{t s})$$

where $K_1$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Here's the differential equation:

$$ tf_{ttt}=sf_s$$

I did computations with Bessel identities and then used Wolfram Alpha to verify the result but I am not confident that it's correct.

> Does $f_t(s)$ satisfy that equation?

Thank you!

Comment: You have $f_t(s)$ in the 1st equation, and $f_s$ in the second one. Do I understand correctly that $f_t(s)=\partial_t f(s, t)$ and $f_s=\partial_s f(s, t)$?

Comment: What exactly $f_{ttt}$ means? Is it $\partial^3/\partial t^3 f(s, t)$?

Comment: Why not writing everything properly and even attaching a Mathematica code to the question? It is really annoying that one has to guess.

Comment: What is  `modified Bessel function of the second kind`? `BesselK[1, #] &`?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as copyable *Mathematica* code as well as images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 4):

```
FullSimplify[t^2*D[f[t, s], {t, 3}] == s^2*D[f[t, s], s] /. 
f -> Function[{t, s}, 2*Sqrt[t/s]*BesselK[1, 2*Sqrt[t*s]]]]

(*True*)
```

Looks like your equation is:
$$t^2 \frac{\partial ^3f(t,s)}{\partial t^3}=s^2 \frac{\partial f(t,s)}{\partial s}$$